# How to get closest tkinter canvas element on click?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a very simple python programming using tkinter. I want to draw some rectangles on a canvas and then when one clicks on a certain rectangle, show the tags of that rectangle. I can't get it to work. The problem seems to be that wherever I click on the canvas, the function get_closest returns 1. Any help is appreciated. This is my first time working with tkinter (and python for that matter), so any remarks about my code that aren't linked to the problems itself, are welcome as well!

```
import tkinter as tk

myrecs = [[None for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

class application:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.frame.grid(row=0)
        self.quitbutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Quit", command = lambda:quit())
        self.quitbutton.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width=200, height=200, bg = "blue")
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.buttonclick)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, columnspan = 2)
        self.tag = self.canvas.create_text(10, 150, text="", anchor="nw") 
        self.makebutton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Make nice canvas", command = self.makecanvas)
        self.makebutton.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)

    def makecanvas(self):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                myrecs[i][j] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(20*i, 20*j, 20*(i+1), 20*(j+1), tags=("rectangle", "i"+str(i), "j"+str(j)))    

    def buttonclick(self, event):
        cnv = self.canvas
        item = cnv.find_closest(cnv.canvasx(event.x), cnv.canvasy(event.y))[0]
        tags = cnv.gettags(item)
        cnv.itemconfigure(self.tag, text=tags[0])  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    app = application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_closest` returns `1` means it's finding the very first element you created within the canvas, which in this case is the `create_text`.

Oddly enough, when you `create_text` with `text=""` it seems to be overtaking all your other elements.  With a simple fix of `text=" "` it will now locate the closet rectangles on clicks.

With the other elements, when you assign `option=""` it actually *disables* (as far as I know) the option so instead of using its default values, you are actively telling `tcl` interpreter to not use it.  This can be observed in other elements like `create_rectangle(..., outline="")` in which the default `outline="black"` will no longer apply, and you won't even get an outline.  I have a feeling `text=""` yield a similar effect and for some reason basically covers the entire canvas area, so it causes `find_closest` to always return that element.  Perhaps if you're lucky @BryanOakley (a tcl expert) can chime in on the backend reasoning.

In fact, if you tried `find_above(item)` you will notice that the `text` is consistently below your other elements drawn afterwards.

**In short:**

```
# Change this:
self.tag = self.canvas.create_text(10, 150, text="", anchor="nw") 

# To this:
self.tag = self.canvas.create_text(10, 150, text=" ", anchor="nw")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! great answer :)